# Mass MP3 audio file editor

Tags: windows-7, mp3

Running Windows 7 64bit, I have a ton of MP3 audio files I would like to crop the same amount of seconds from the beginning of the audio, is there a Free application that can accomplish this? If no free applications please recommend others.

EDIT: I need something with a gui, no command line software if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me guess: trim the intro music off of podcasts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to perform batch actions (called "chains") on any number of audio files. You'd load in the files, create a chain that trims the necessary number of seconds, and apply the chain to all the files you wish to affect.

Comment: Wow, I have used that software before, did not know it would do what I needed, thanks I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the hours to learn Audacity or chaining, I will however accept your answer, it can be done with Audacity.

Comment: @geodave: you cannot do that with Audacity. None of the chain commands trim as wanted.

Comment: Audacity doesn't allow directly working with MP3's last I used it.

Answer (score 2):

[dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) has a nice GUI and can batch process audio files and has a [DSP Effects](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dbpoweramp-dsp.htm) plugin which includes the ability to trim a fixed amount of time from the beginning or end of a set of files in any of its supported formats.  Unlike SoX and Audacity (the other answers), it looks like mp3 is one of the supported formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [**SoX**](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can handle this although I'd recommend some reading. It sounds like you're after the "trim" feature.

Comment: This generation has been babied way too much with GUIs.

Comment: Define "this generation"

Comment: People who have grown up with nothing but Windows.

Comment: Yeah, and those people who have grown up with nothing but automobiles, geez, what is this world coming to. ;->

Comment: That too. Not a lot of people appreciate a good **walk** these days, hence the obesity problem some countries have.

Comment: You assume way too much JohnT

Comment: Playing smart doesn't fly with me ;)

Comment: Looks like quite a bit of work is required to get this to accept mp3 files.